# Finding group generated by given permutations

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $\sigma = (3 4),\tau=(1 3 2), \nu=(1 2 3 4)$. I know that $\sigma\notin A_4$ since it is an odd permutation, so  how can I find the group which generated by these three permutations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $S_n$ is generated by any $n$-cycle and any $2$-cycle of adjacent elements in the $n$-cycle.